# Как в Xamarin поменять заголовок приложения (android:label)?

Tags: xamarin, label

Меняю в AndroidManifest.xml, меняю в MainActivity.cs (

```
[Activity(Label = "@string/ApplicationName", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
```

)
Пересобираю проект, но в Main.axml ничего не меняется.

Answer (score 2):

Что у тебя проставлено в ресурсах?(путь Resources -> Values -> String.xml) Что соответствует атрибуту **ApplicationName** ?
На худой конец,можешь напрямую в свойство **Label** установить свое значение :

```
Activity(Label = "MoePrilojenie", , MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
```